# Query relations within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of `entities` that can have many-to-many relations to each other, using a second `junction` table. At a first glance, the design may seem flawed and suggests a separate table for each type of entity. The thing is, that the entities are generic, and completely user-defined. They may also be connected completely ad-hoc and each entity can have an unlimited number of connections.
Here is a simplified example of my tables:

```
Entities
------------
Entity  | Id | Type
-------------------
Event   | 1  | Request
Stroll  | 2  | Activity
Dinner  | 3  | Activity
Angela  | 4  | Person
Anders  | 5  | Person
Michael | 6  | Person

Junctions
----------------
Left    | Right
----------------
1       | 2    // Connect Request -> Stroll
2       | 4    // Connect Stroll -> Angela
1       | 3    // Connect Request -> Dinner
3       | 5    // Connect Dinner -> Anders
3       | 6    // Connect Dinner -> Michael
```

Now to my question:

I would like to perfom queries from the view-point of different entities. Lets say I would like to look at **Requests** and see what **Activities** they have, and any **Persons** attending each activity. I would like to get a result like this:

```
Request  | Activity | Person
-----------------------------
Event    | Stroll   | Angela
         | Dinner   | Anders
                    | Michael
```

I would also, for example, like to be able to flip the coin and look at **Persons** And see what **Requests** they attend, like this:

```
Person  | Request
-----------------
Angela  | Event
Anders  | Event
Michael | Event
```

How can i write queries to achieve results like this, and is it even possible with the current structure? I have spent much time on googling and trials with no luck, and I am very grateful for any help.

Here is an [***SQLFiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/175d04/2)

Comment: You spent so much time to format your question properly. why not just use  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) instead?

Comment: I am glad you recognize my tremendous efforts in making my question plesant to read. Next time, I'll use SQLFiddle instead, as you suggest. Thank you

Comment: I have never used it, but I'll give it a try. Just give me a moment

Comment: Does right column on Junctions contain always persons?

Comment: @Alexander: Ok, so here is an attempt. I wrote a select-query as well, to help you understand what I'm trying to do. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/175d04/2)

Comment: @Kuzgun: No, in this example Left or Right does not have a hierarchical meaning. I'm happy to change the junction table if that helps, as long as it doesn't affect the fact that the entities can be connected in any way. In the best of worlds, I would like to event be able to connect two persons

Comment: I believe Type is user defined too, so you need to use Pivot

Comment: @Kuzgun: Yes, you are right about Type. In the real-world application, Type is actually a Foreign Key. How would you use Pivot to achieve the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you do it

```
SELECT e1.Entity Request,
       e2.Entity Activity,
       e3.Entity Person
  FROM Junctions j1 
       JOIN Junctions j2 
            ON j1.`Right` = j2.`Left`
       JOIN Entities e1
            ON j1.`Left` = e1.Id
       JOIN Entities e2
            ON j1.`Right` = e2.Id
       JOIN Entities e3
            ON j2.`Right` = e3.Id;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/175d04/55)

To help you understand - at first I joined `Junctions` on itself like that:

```
SELECT j1.`Left` Request, 
       j1.`Right` Activity,  
       j2.`Right` Person  
  FROM Junctions j1 
       JOIN Junctions j2 
            ON j1.`Right` = j2.`Left`;
```

And then joined to the `Entity`, as you can see, to replace the `Id`s. One time for each `type`.

But, nevertheless, I still think that this architecture is horrible, and it needs to be redesigned.

Comment: This seems like just what I'm after. What I don't understand is why you create the 'j2' join, except that it makes it work. I'll figure it out though. Thank you very much for your time and effort. This will be of great help, and once I fully understand it, I can use it as foundation for further queries.

Comment: I created j2' join in order to fetch request-activity-person in one line.

Comment: The examples I used are simplified and not whats used in the actual application, where, for example, Type is an INT and FK. When you say that the architecture is horrible; what would you suggest? I'm open for re-design.
In the application, "Entity" has user-created child tables containing type specific columns. The application is a sort of CMS tool for bookings of any kind, requiring a great deal of flexibility

Comment: It's hard to say without specific details. Probably, you should post another question with expanded explanation on what do you want from database. When you do - make sure you have used tags `database` and `database-design`. I think you'll get some useful suggestions (although, I can't guarantee it will come from me).